# PHP pthreads count active threads?

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I want to write some PHP Code with pthreads. For this pthreads I need to know how many threads are active. Because the next system can only handle e fixed number of requests. I can count the started threads, but I can't subtract when a thread has stopped.

I tried to to count with count on the threads object, but I also doesn't subtract. How can I manage, that I get a information to my starting script if a thread has finished his work?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, i have limited knowledge with pthreads, but i did use i awhile back and i create a table in a db with the thread number and a boolean (named Busy). When the thread starts, it writes to the table True, and just before it finishes it writes false. You can then reference that table at any time to see which threads are in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way to get the information about running and not running threads. So I can count them. If some one has a better solution I'm happy to see it. But first I want to share my own solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
class AsyncOperation extends Thread
{
    public function __construct($threadId)
    {
        $this->threadId = $threadId;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        printf("T %s: Sleeping 3sec\n", $this->threadId);
        sleep(1);
        printf("T %s: Hello World\n", $this->threadId); 
        $this->kill;
    }
}
$a=0; 
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $test[$i] = new AsyncOperation($i);
    $test[$i]->start();
}
$arg=true;
while($arg){
    $arg=false;
    foreach($test as $key => $object){
//    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $arg2=$object->isRunning();
        if($arg2){
            $arg=$arg2;
        }else{
            //var_dump($key);
            unset ($test[$key]);
        }
//var_dump($key);
if(!$arg){
var_dump($arg);
}
    }
}
var_dump($test);
echo count($test)."\n";
echo "\n".microtime(true) - $start . "\n";
echo "end\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems, what you need is a thread pool.
this might be interesting to read upon.

a pool class, is a collection of a worker threads.
with a adjustable thread count, you can set a pool with specific count of worker threads to do a list of jobs, multi-threaded way.

lets say, you only want to create 3 threads, working on 10 jobs.

```
<?php

class MyWork extends Threaded {

    public $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        echo "Constructing worker $name \n";
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function run() {
        echo "Worker $this->name start running\n";
        $strMem = '[mem:' . (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024). 'MB]';

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            /*
                random delay is to simulate different time it takes for this worker to process the job.
                in the real work, this is where the job is done
            */
            $delay = rand(1,5); //busy... busy...

            echo "Worker $this->name : $i process in [$delay s] $strMem  \n";
            sleep($delay);
        }
    }
}

class MyWorker extends Worker {
    public function run() {}
}

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 7200);
    ini_set('output_buffering ',0);

    $sJob = "A";//starting job
    $iMaxJob = 10;//max job
    $iMaxThread = 3;//create a pool for 3 worker;

    $pool = new Pool($iMaxThread); 

    //start queing jobs;
    for ($i=1; $i <= $iMaxJob; $i++){
        $pool->submit(new MyWork($sJob++));
    }

    $pool->shutdown();
    $strMem = '[peak:' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024). 'MB]';

    echo "done. " . $strMem;

?>
```